# Change Navlink css class from Active to own on Blazor

Tags: c#, css, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Im trying to change what class is rendered when using navlink, done an old two year answer which was rolling my own navlink and using @getActive() but that wasnt super helpful.

Looking though the documentation it says

> Optionally, assign a CSS class name to NavLink.ActiveClass to apply a custom CSS class to the rendered link when the current route matches the href. [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

and in Microsoft fashion it just shows
`public string? ActiveClass { get; set; }`

which I tried just adding this at the top of the @code section and defaulted that to "test" for now, however when looking at the link changes its still applying the "Active" css class.

Has anyone use this "ActionClass" and make it then pass in this Class name and in turn overwrite the "Active" default class.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you set `ActiveClass` parameter:

```
<NavLink ActiveClass="my-active-class" class="nav-link" href="counter">
    <span class="oi oi-plus" aria-hidden="true"></span> Counter
</NavLink>
```